# omitir una parte de la función en evento onclick en javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

Tengo una duda que no sé si se puede hacer. Tengo la siguiente función de javascript:

```
<script>
        function clean_and_show(ckType, theme){
    //First function to clean
    var ckName = document.getElementsByName(ckType.name);
    var checked = document.getElementById(ckType.id);
    if (checked.checked) {
        for(var i=0; i < ckName.length; i++){
            if(!ckName[i].checked){
                ckName[i].disabled = true;
            }else{
                ckName[i].disabled = false;
            }
        }
            }
            else {
                for(var i=0; i < ckName.length; i++){
                    ckName[i].disabled = false;
                }
            }

    //Second one
    var x = document.getElementById(theme);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
    }
```

Quiero que un evento Onclick solo utilice la parte segunda 'theme', pero no sé si se podrá hacer.

```
<div class="col-2">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="progress" id="pri" 
   onclick="clean_and_show(undefined,'asignaturas')"> Primero
  </label>
                    </div>
```

Como veis he probado a poner undefined pero no sé como se podría omitir.

Gracias de antemano,

Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que encerrar la primera parte dentro de un if donde verificas si ckType es diferente de `undefined`:

```js
function clean_and_show(ckType, theme){
    // Verifica que el parámetro no sea indefinido
    if(typeof ckType !== 'undefined') {
        //First function to clean
        var ckName = document.getElementsByName(ckType.name);
        var checked = document.getElementById(ckType.id);
        if (checked.checked) {
            for(var i=0; i < ckName.length; i++){
                if(!ckName[i].checked){
                    ckName[i].disabled = true;
                }else{
                    ckName[i].disabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            for(var i=0; i < ckName.length; i++){
                ckName[i].disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    //Second one
    var x = document.getElementById(theme);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-2">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="progress" id="pri" 
   onclick="clean_and_show(undefined,'asignaturas')"> Primero
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Vaya máquina estás hecho